# Extjs Chained store to GlobalStore in ViewModel

Tags: extjs

I want to use a store that in chained to global store,
but after launch I gives js warning:

```
Ext.data.Store created with no model
```

and i cannot see any data.

**Here is my code:**

*Global UserStore*

```
Ext.define('App.store.UserStore',{
extend      : 'App.store.AjaxReadyStore',
requires    : ['App.model.UserModel'],
model       : 'App.model.UserModel',
autoLoad    : false,
id          : 'UserStore',
alias       : 'store.UserStore',


constructor : function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.proxy.api= {
        create  : 'api/v1/users',
        read    : 'api/v1/users',
        update  : 'api/v1/users',
        destroy : 'api/v1/users'
    };
    this.readAndLoad();
}
});
```

*ViewModel*

```
Ext.define('App.view.tasktemplate.TaskTemplateModel', {
    extend  : 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias   : 'viewmodel.tasktemplate',
    stores : {
        owner: {
            source  : 'UserStore'
        }
    }
});
```

*View*

```
Ext.define('App.view.tasktemplate.TaskTemplateOwnerList',{
    extend  : 'App.view.pool.grid.GridWithAction',
    xtype   : 'tasktemplateownerlist',
    store: {
        bind : '{owner}'
    },
});
```

Comment: plus1 - this is interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your view code to this -

```
Ext.define('App.view.tasktemplate.TaskTemplateOwnerList',{
        extend  : 'App.view.pool.grid.GridWithAction',
        xtype   : 'tasktemplateownerlist',
        bind: {
            store : '{owner}'
        }
    });
```

Store Binding:

```
bind: {
     store : '{owner}'
}
```

It's actually interesting when you do

```
store: {
        bind : '{owner}'
    }
```

inside your view - The StoreManager does a lookup with the value of the store config, usually expecting a string or array of strings (store name) but it sees that it's not a string but an object so it creates a instance of 'Ext.data.Store' passing {bind:'{owner}'} as config -> so you actually get an instance of the Store class with no models associated. 
store: